# HttpClient - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host - IIS Published web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, json.net

I have tried a ton of solutions that I searched about this issue, but none of them fixed my web app.

So, I have a web app that uses a vendor API to populate my data. I was able to successfully connect to the API and transact different kinds of API calls locally.

After I completed my web app, I tried to publish it to my DEV IIS environment. Unfortunately, it throws below server error:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

And the stack trace:

> [SocketException (0x2746): An existing connection was forcibly closed
>   by the remote host]
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +8370007    System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
>
> [IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.]
>   System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +294
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar) +149
>
> [WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected
>   error occurred on a send.]
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +729    System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>   +77
>
> [HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.]
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +60    CampaignMonitor.Web.Utilities.d__2.MoveNext()
>   +411    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +60    CampaignMonitor.Web.Controllers.d__0.MoveNext()
>   +877    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +92
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +72    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +387    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +387    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +38    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +188
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +38
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +68
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +39    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +38
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +43
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +68
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +38    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
>   +212    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +166

I have below HttpClient setup but error still persist:

```
    private static HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(API_KEY, "")
    };

    private static HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; EN; rv:11.0) like Gecko");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");
        return client;
    }
```

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json and Newtonsoft.Json.Linq but not sure if they have something to do with the issue.

**But then again, the issue doesn't show when I published it using Visual Studio during debugging, but only shows when published in my DEV IIS server.**

Hopeful for some guidance on this.

Comment: Probably the error is on the server side code. In case like these having a detailed log of the server code flow is essential.

Comment: @Steve - do you have some advice on how I could capture the server side error? Error happens when I published it to IIS, so I'm unsure how to debug the server side code.

Comment: I don't understand. Have you written the server side code or not? If yes then you need to add some kind of logging to your server side code. Use libraries like NLog or Log4Net, add log statement when you enter a method, when you exit and when you catch an exception. Allow these libraries to create files in your server APP_DATA folder where you can examine them post-mortem.

Comment: @Steve - Oh, okay. I'll try it. I thought there's a way to have some sort of breakpoints :D my bad.